# Groovy JDBC eachrow headers for a csv file

Tags: jenkins, jdbc, groovy

I have a Jenkins Groovy script that runs a JDBC query with the intention of outputting the result to a CSV file. The code runs fine if I can predict the query, I can manually produce a CSV file based on a known number of columns.

The problem comes when I have the query available as a build parameter. I want to write code that is able to handle any number of columns, including aliases if required.

The output from this code;

```
sql.eachRow(query){ row ->
System.out.println row
}
```

is;

```
[ID:12345, date:2019-11-01 11:23:45, name:bob]
[ID:23456, date:2019-11-10 33:22:11, name:jim]
```

And what I need is;

```
ID,date,name
12345,2019-11-01 11:23:45,bob
23456,2019-11-10 33:22:11,jim
```

And I want to do this without having to put column names in the code. If I do;

```
System.out.println row[0] + "," + row[1] + "," + row[2]
```

It gets me the data in the desired format. But it doesn't give me the column names, or even the number of columns. And I'm probably breaking all kinds of rules by treating it as an array.

I think I might be asking how to get a list of methods in a class, but I only want the column names rather than all the methods available.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the headers, but it is not in the same result set as your eachRow(query) result set:

```
    println sql.firstRow(query).keySet().collect().join(",")
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, managed to sort it. It was all in the metadata...

```
def md = row.getMetaData()
dec colCount = md.columnCount
```

Once I had the column count, I could create a loop to get the column names;

```
md.getColumnName(loop)
```